# Conditional expression to obtain resource

Tags: qlikview

I need an expression for showing either green up arrows or red down arrows; it'd look something like this:

```
if sum(Revenu) - Sum(BudgetAmount) > 0 green up arrow (else) red down arrow
```

This is what I'm trying to show:

[image: Screenshot of desired behaviour]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use chr(9650) as an UP arrow and chr(9660) as a DOWN arrow. You can use the Text Color field to do conditional Red/Green formatting.

So you can say this for example:

```
=if(sum(Revenu)-Sum(BudgetAmount)>0,chr(9650),chr(9660))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two images (green arrow and red arrow), and use a condition in that elements to show depends of the value (sum(Revenu) - Sum(BudgetAmount) > 0).